# Current source with base resistance

Tags: power, amplifier, current-source

I need to know how the resistor (named beta compensation in some books) can be calculated. It's clear that BE of Q6 voltage will drop on (2.2k + 68 Ohm). But what the current will be through 68 Ohm resistor? If there is no 2.2k it's clear that the current will be 0.7V/68 Ohm.

[image]

Comment: I do not believe this circuit has any "beta compensation" at all. Beta compensation is used when the base current is an issue. In this circuit it isn't since 1) the beta of these type of transistors (BC556) is quite high 2) the base current of Q5 and Q7 isn't even flowing through Q6 but through the 2 10 k resistors. This circuit works as long as the two 10 k resistors provide enough base current for Q6 and Q7. Then Q6 will "steal" all the base current that is not needed such that there will be around 0.6 V across the 68 ohms emitter resistor.

Comment: I think the 2.2 k ohm base resistor will not drop much DC voltage because Ic of Q6 will be small as the two 10 k resistors cannot make much current flow. The base current of Q6 will be beta times smaller. I think the 2.2 k ohm resistor is there to improve the dynamic behavior as it makes the loopgain of the local loop Q6 and Q7 a bit smaller. You'd have to do a small signal analysis to see that.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie  the 10k+10k is chosen to overdrive the base current due to hFE reduction when Vce=Vce(sat) and Q6 absorbs the excess current from the fixed R to keep Vbe relatively constant, so this could be called "beta compensation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for Q6 to operate as a CC source when hFE drops rapidly below Vce=2V, the base current must be increased to at least 3% of Ic.  When Vce=Vce(sat) the hFE is only 10 or base current of 10%.  BUT, Q6-b input ESR or incremental impedance drops to the low base spreading resistance when saturated, and this could bypass some of the emitter current in Q7 and increase the current source value near saturation, thus there are limits to Rb for min and maximum.

The ratio of Rb to Re (current sense) depends on high hFE devices but a ratio of 33:1 is a good ratio.

Comment: May you tell about 33:1 in according to schematic, how it's used to find 2.2k value?

Comment: If 10k+10k from ~20Vdc gives ~ <1mA into base current or 10% of  Q7-e.   Q6 prevents Q7-e exceeding 0.7V/68R=10 mA roughly. Thus base current must be at least 10% of 1mA or 1% of current thru 68R. assumes low hFE =10 squared = 100 hence 1% works for low Vce. In this case 3% or 68R * 33 = 2k2

Comment: Please write more detailed explanation from "Thus base..." I can't understand how it works!

Comment: Do you know how common emitter gain works ? with negative feedback collector to base ?

Comment: Yes, I know how that schematic works! "Thus base current..." base current of what BJT?

Comment: Do you know how to estimate transistor input and output impedance using emitter Re*hFE for base and inputRb/hFE for emitter ? Since Vbe vs Ib has high gain curve and and hFE6*hFE7 has a minimum gain of 10*10 and maximum maybe 200*200, use worst case minimum to see how V(68R) stays reasonbly constant with Vcc variations at 0.65V +/-30mV

Comment: @MaxMil There is a complicated answer that involves the variation of Vbe with temperature, variation of beta with temperature, and a host of other details, which forms a kind of parabolic response to select the resistor value. There is also a much simpler answer that doesn't form a parabola and is just a matter of design choices. All of these ***must*** include \$r_e=\frac{V_{BE}}{I_C}\$ for \$Q_6\$ as part of the equation used to find your \$2.2\:\textrm{k}\Omega\$ value, though.The base resistor value *must* obviously depend upon the \$Q_6\$ collector current. So that term must be present.

Comment: Reduce 2.2k to zero raise Q6 Vbe and thus lower constant current. It also make Q6-Ib more sensitive to burning out from excessive Vbe variations so 2.2k is also to limit base current. In a simple DC regulated current limiter, you can use 0 ohms for Rb

Comment: @jonk May you present any simple equation to find 2.2k Ohm value?

Comment: @Tony Stewart. EE since '75 "use worst case minimum to see how V(68R) stays reasonbly constant..." how it can be seen - using equations or with simulator?

Comment: @MaxMil  can you define max load current variations thru 16R load?  This affects Vbe and thus Ib and the reason why 2.2k must have been chosen.

Comment: @Tony Stewart. EE since '75 You write "Reduce 2.2k to zero raise Q6 Vbe and thus lower constant current..." When Vbe raise why the current lowering? I=Vbe/68Ohm, if Vbe raise then the I must raise too, or it's not so?

Comment: 2.2k serves to limit base current but the max value depends on R ratios.  When Q6 conducts more, then Q7 conducts less, thus lower current output.